# Variable iterates twice (only supposed to once) in a single loop in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, for-loop

I have an issue where a number is printing twice when it should only be printing once before some output. I'll be highlighting the most relevant content, but to give context, I'll provide the entirety of my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I load the out put of a `ps aux` into an array.

```
N=0
for i in $(ps aux | awk '{print $11,$4}' | grep -v 0.0 | grep -v MEM | sort) ; do

array[$N]="$i"

let "N= $N + 1"
done
```

Here I split the array into two arrays

```
N=0

for i in `seq 0 ${#array[@]}`; do

if [ $(( $i % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then arrayb[$N]=${array[$i]} ; else arrayc[$N]=${array[$i]} ;fi

let "N= $N + 1"

done
```

Now I look to combine duplicate entries (please pardon some of the convoluted variable naming; I was taking shots in the dark trying to trouble shoot).

```
N=0
c=0

for i in `seq 0 ${#arrayb[@]}`; do

let "B= $N - 1"

A=`echo ${arrayb[$B]} | tr -d '\n'`
B=`echo ${arrayb[$N]} | tr -d '\n'`

#A=${arrayb[$B]}
#B=${arrayb[$N]}
```

Here is where I check to see if the former array element is equal to the latter. If so combine and remove.

```
#if [ "$A" = "$B" ]; then 
#arrayc[$N]=$(bc <<< ${arrayc[$N]}+${arrayc[$B]}); unset arrayb[$B];unset arrayc[$B]; echo trololo
#echo derp
#fi
```

The important part though is this. `echo $c` then I `echo $A $B`. My output however shows the following:

```
0
 awk
1
awk 
2
 -bash
3
-bash 
4
 -bash
```

When it should be something like:

```
0
 awk
awk 
2
 -bash
-bash 
3
```

---

```
echo $c
echo -n "$A" "$B"

echo ""
let "c=$c+1"


let "N= $N + 1"
done
```

What I can't wrap my head around is how it prints `a` then `c` then `b` then `c` when it's all the same loop. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What is signally lacking from this question is an explanation of the purpose of the script or a description of the required output.  The two `grep -v` operations could be done with the `awk`.  The array work would be better handled by `while read name memory` and then assigning `$name` and `$memory` to the appropriate array.  It would also help if the code was indented, and if the complete script was all in one place — rather than forcing us to assemble a script from disjoint fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `for` loop can be simplified to:

```
array=( $(ps aux | awk '$4 != 0.0 && $4 !~ /MEM/ {print $11,$4}' | sort) )
```

When written as a single fragment, the second loop is:

```
N=0
for i in `seq 0 ${#array[@]}`
do
    if [ $(( $i % 2 )) -eq 0 ]
    then arrayb[$N]=${array[$i]}
    else arrayc[$N]=${array[$i]}
    fi
    ((N++))
done
```

You are incrementing N every iteration, so you have `arrayb[0]` containing a name and `arrayc[1]` containing the corresponding memory usage. You should probably be using:

```
for i in `seq 0 ${#array[@]}`
do
    if [ $(( $i % 2 )) -eq 0 ]
    then arrayb[$((i/2))]=${array[$i]}
    else arrayc[$((i/2))]=${array[$i]}
    fi
done
```

However, you'd probably do better again to combine the first assignment with the second loop:

```
ps aux | awk '$4 != 0.0 && $4 !~ /MEM/ {print $11,$4}' | sort |
while read name memory
do
     arrayb+=($name)
     arrayc+=($memory)
done
```

The only snag here is that the arrays are set in a sub-shell which exits.  Fortunately, `bash` provides [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to evade that problem:

```
arrayb=()
arrayc=()
while read name memory
do
     arrayb+=($name)
     arrayc+=($memory)
done < <(ps aux | awk '$4 != 0.0 && $4 !~ /MEM/ {print $11,$4}' | sort)
```

Then your code currently is written as:

```
N=0
c=0

for i in `seq 0 ${#arrayb[@]}`; do

    let "B= $N - 1"

    A=`echo ${arrayb[$B]} | tr -d '\n'`
    B=`echo ${arrayb[$N]} | tr -d '\n'`
    echo $c
    echo -n "$A" "$B"
    echo ""
    let "c=$c+1"
    let "N= $N + 1"

done
```

And you've got a problem because you access `arrayb` twice and ignore `arrayc`.  You also seem to be going through contortions to undo the unwanted incrementing in the original code for the second loop.

The use of back-ticks is generally a bad idea; use `$(...)` instead. The `tr -d '\n'` should be unnecessary. The use of `echo -n "$A" "$B"` followed immediately by `echo ""` is odd: `echo "$A" "$B"` would suffice?

```
for i in $(seq 0 ${#arrayb[@]})
do
    echo "${arrayb[$i]}" "${arrayc[$i]}"
done
```

So, we can reduce the script provided so far to:

```
arrayb=()
arrayc=()
while read name memory
do
     arrayb+=($name)
     arrayc+=($memory)
done < <(ps aux | awk '$4 != 0.0 && $4 !~ /MEM/ {print $11,$4}' | sort)

for i in $(seq 0 ${#arrayb[@]})
do
    echo "${arrayb[$i]}" "${arrayc[$i]}"
done
```

From here, you can continue with the two arrays, `arrayb` and `arrayc`, organized so that matching indexes contain comparable values.

Comment: I know it says not to use comments to say thanks, but your code is terse and your explanation verbose. While I still am reviewing some of the concepts you've provided here, I wanted to say thank you.